# Android Studio меняет значение android:text (ну не совсем). Что делать?

Tags: android-studio

В android:text я указываю ссылку на значение переменной из strings.xml, но вместо того, чтобы показать, что я именно ввел, он выводит значение переменной. Как это убрать?
P.S. Может быть, я сейчас сказал бред. Я новичок в android и в android studio, прост)

Comment: Код XML со значением переменной выложите и код как вы указываете ссылку.

Comment: все. решил проблему. надо было просто 2 раза кликнуть на значение переменной